# How to check if window.onpopstate in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application I want to preserve applied filters on browser back button event.

To accomplish this, I did below code.

```
componentWillMount() {
 const { list, checkReportClose, updateReportCloseStatus } = this.props;
 const { inPopState } = this.state;
  window.onpopstate = () => {
   if (!_.isEmpty(list)) {
    this.setState({ filters: JSON.parse(list.input.filters), inPopState: true}, this.loadList);
   }
  }
 if(!inPopState && inPopState != undefined && checkReportClose == false) {
  this.loadList();
 }
}
```

As per above while I am coming back to this page by hitting back button, it will check for the `window.onpopstate` and process the filters and call the `loadlist` api. I am updating the state `inPopState` to `true`.
Now as you can see in if condition I am checking for `inPopState` and if it is `false` then only `loadList` api calls. But in my case even though I am updating state it calls the `loadList` API twice.

I want to check if condition over `window.onpopstate` if it is then it will `loadlist` with filter else without filters.

Comment: i deleted my incorrect answer so i don't mislead future readers.  the basic idea for detecting a back navigation using redux would be to call an action to set the lastViewedFilters when the filter changes.  Then in componentDidMount you can check the lastViewedFilter against the current filter (list.input.filters).  If it's the same value, you know this is a back navigation and the current list is valid, otherwise it's a fresh page view.

Comment: In your case if you aren't using redux, substitute 'redux' for 'parent component state' and pass it as a prop.

Comment: Hi brub, I have posted the same question with more description. Can you please look and help me with that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034349/how-to-preserve-applied-filters-on-browser-back-button-in-react-js?noredirect=1