# How to preserve applied filters on browser back button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

In my application, there are filters on all list pages.
Now as per requirement, I want to preserve applied filters on browser back button.
E.g say user has applied filters on sales list page.
After that he clicks on one record to go to sales edit page.
Now if user hit browser back button then those applied filters should remain.
To accomplish this i did like below.
On sales list page ,

```
  componentWillMount() {
  const { list, checkReportClose, 
    updateReportCloseStatus } = this.props;
   const { inPopState } = this.state;
    window.onpopstate = () => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(list)) {
     this.setState({ filters: JSON.parse(list.input.filters), 
       inPopState: true}, this.loadList);
    }
   }
   if(!inPopState && inPopState != undefined && 
   checkReportClose == false) {
     this.loadList();
   }
   }
```

Using above code it works fine but while back button it calls the lis page api (this.loadList) twise.

Please suggest some new solution or modification in existing one.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use localstorage to save filters values and when user comes back to the same page again the get your saved values from localstorage and pass them to the api you are calling

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the url to store filters as parameters.

I've written an example below. Let's use `http://skylerfenn.com/news?order=asc&category=feature&year=2017` as the url for the functions below.

Step 1: Call `getParameters()` in the `window.onpopstate` and store the parameters in state. Using the URL above, `getParameters()` will return the parameters as the object `{ order: 'asc', category: 'feature', year: '2017' }`.

```
function getParameters() {
  let parameters = window.location.search.replace('?', '');

  let currentParameters = {};

  if (Object.keys(parameters).length) {

    parameters = parameters.split('&');

    for (let i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
      let parameter = parameters[i].split('=');
      currentParameters[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
    }

  }

  return currentParameters;
}
```

Step 2: Pass any new parameters to the `getNewParameters` function below as an object. For example, calling `getNewParameters({ order: 'desc', year: null })` returns the object `{ order: 'desc', category: 'feature' }`. Notice that it removes year since it's null.

```
function getNewParameters(newParameters) {
  const parameters = getParameters();

  const keys = Object.keys(newParameters);

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const value = newParameters[keys[i]];

    parameters[keys[i]] = value;

    if (!value) {
      delete parameters[keys[i]];
    }
  }

  return parameters;
}
```

Step 3: Use the result from `getNewParameters` to update state. Also pass the result to function below to update your url.

```
updateUrl(parameters) {
  let search = '';
  let j = 0;
  let separator = '?';

  Object.keys(parameters).forEach((key) => {

    let value = parameters[key];

    if (value) {

      if (j !== 0) {
        separator = '&';
      }

      search += `${separator}${key}=${value}`;

      j++;
    }
  });

  let newUrl = `${location.origin}${location.pathname}${search}`;

  // prevents pushing same url if function won't change url.
  if (location.href !== newUrl) {
    history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
  }
}
```